# Stop ofono daemon

Tags: services

How to stop temporarily/disable `ofonod` in Ubuntu?

The following command didn't work for me:

```
sudo service ofono stop
```

I want to run the `ofono` in debug mode. I copied the executable file (Which i got using `which ofono` command)to a new folder. Once I am able to stop `ofonod`, I will run this from new location like `./ofono -d`.

I can't see any entries in `init.rd` or any of the `rc.` folders. But I need to stop it first.

How is this possible?

Comment: Please what version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Check for it in the `/etc/systemd/system`, with `ls -al /etc/systemd/system | grep ofono` perhaps its a _systemd service_

Comment: Hi George, I am using Ubuntu version 14.04

Comment: @George, I checked in that path, But I couldn't find anything related to ofono.

Comment: Hi Geroge, I am getting file not exist error.

Comment: please check in the `/etc/init.d` dir, and check the status of `ofono` with `service --status-all | grep ofono`

Comment: To disable `ofono` do `update-rc.d ofono disable`

Answer (score 0):

[ConnMan wiki](https://wiki.kubuntu.org/ConnMan/Debugging)

> The easy way to enable debug logs
>
> The easiest way to enable debug logs is to run this command:
>
> ```
> indicator-network-debug start
> ```
>
> This will restart `connman` and `ofono` in debug mode, and also
>   enables debug mode in indicator-network-service. All log messages will
>   go to `/var/log/syslog` and there will be a lots of them.
>
> Warning! Debug logs contain a lot of information and there might some
>   confidential information, for example passwords. Always be careful
>   when sending debug logs to public so that you don't reveal anything
>   sensitive by accident.
>
> To disable debug logs:
>
> ```
> indicator-network-debug stop
> ```
>
> Alternative method to disable debug logs is to reboot the computer.
>   The system will run normally again.

At the same wiki page it explain that`restart ofono` should be done as follows:

```
sudo restart ofono
```

Comment: Iam getting a 'indicator-network-debug: command not found' error. I am using ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Get the binary of ofono using `which ofono` commmand. 
For time being, remove the binary from that path to some other folder of your convenience, then kill ofonod.

Now run from new path as

```
./ofonod -nd -P ril
```

If you want to get the response in a file, use:

```
./ofonod -nd -P ril  OfonoDebug.txt 2>&1
```

Change the owner if you want using `chmod 777 OfonoDebug.txt`.